# How to allow host for mobile app connexion to django rest framework api?

Tags: react-native, heroku, django-rest-framework, hosting

I build a backend with django rest framework.I hosted my API on heroku and it works well with my frontend web app, but not with the mobile app build with react-native. Which host should I add in django settings file to allow connexion for mobile apps?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you are using django-cors-headers to allow for your web apps to access your REST API. Usually, you add origins like this:

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "https://example.com",
    "https://sub.example.com",
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://127.0.0.1:9000",
]
```

I don't think there is a special route that you could use to allow your api for your mobile app specifically but what you can do is that, you can make your API to be access by all origins. You can do something like this in your settings.py file instead of specifying the origins.

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

And then hide your API route so that people don't mess with it. I hope this helps!